# How to move div above in a column in grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am new to css grid and so I was playing around with css in codepen and I was wondering what I should write to be able to move a div up to fill the location left by the other divs. [This is my codepen](https://codepen.io/iljones00/pen/GRZpjLO?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=ac3d7cd5cfcda9e8254bd8dd2d18b0c033312fa0-1597137880-0-AbxJIpTOTFhEn3V0Ef1fLD1iWLd-yNFl1L9rEiy5xaAVOzjjngf23GOx1oayYo1bgGLLWflqvnheimT-fCT8dU9P601rysH6KjKRPS5c0eSDzyvIxOejd5K5b8Yx8AfrXEFQpSMZUe7Nu8iCnCG0RIoAVI2cSzxX9jOhrZky_fUFDKF6KAXA3Jw1Si0va-iYTARa-OgQNuneA5i5yHnaH-QSfvHhTqdqaFrhCQUG96nJEuxfbGBSODR9pbf-bvhoCXaTwpOxpdAsRMTgXdZiiZgAwRQZDwqAhJRX1PfTmyob4gHtIZ1DdLHYb74l2HvPNGCubclF6jAVllK5LTU2z14)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.c {
  height: 200px;
}

.d, .e { 
  grid-column: 1;
}

.f {
  
}
```

How can I get box f to float up to where the other two boxes were? Also what happens when box c is larger and I want to bottom align box f with box c?

Answer (score 0):

add `grid-auto-flow: dense;align-items: end;`

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  align-items: end;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.d,
.e {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.c {
  height: 200px;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hardcoded but you can use `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` to determine which row should element start/end.

So if you add this to `.f` element, it should expand from the second row to the fifth.

```
.f {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rows of an element with  grid-row. In this case would be like **grid-row: 2/5** to the **.f** element